# Animating google maps polyline with setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to view a path on google maps using javascript and jsp. So, basically my code works as follows: the coordinates are in the text files and the content is saved in arrays and passed through jsp to javascript. I just want to make an animation of this, so that I could see how the polyline is being updated. When I use the function setTiemout() in the for loop, I just see the map without any path. In any case, I tried just to visualize the final path and it works fine. The problem is in the way I should use the setTimeout() function in the for loop. Could anyone experienced in javascript give a hint? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.DataInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
    String nextX, nextY;
    String [] x = null;
    String [] y = null;
    ArrayList<String> x_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> y_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileInputStream x_stream = new FileInputStream("T:\\Java_projects\\GPS_Tracking\\src\\x.txt"); 
    FileInputStream y_stream = new FileInputStream("T:\\Java_projects\\GPS_Tracking\\src\\y.txt"); 
    DataInputStream x_input = new DataInputStream(x_stream);
    DataInputStream y_input = new DataInputStream(y_stream);
    BufferedReader x_buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    x_input));
    BufferedReader y_buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    y_input));

    while ((nextX = x_buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        nextX.trim();
        if (nextX.length() != 0) {
    x_list.add(nextX);
        }
    }
    while ((nextY = y_buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        nextY.trim();
        if (nextY.length() != 0) {
    y_list.add(nextY);
        }
    }
    x = (String[])x_list.toArray(new String[x_list.size()]);
    y = (String[])y_list.toArray(new String[y_list.size()]);

     Double [] gps_x = new Double[x.length];
     Double [] gps_y = new Double[y.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    gps_x[i] = Double.parseDouble(x[i]);
    gps_y[i] = Double.parseDouble(y[i]);    
    }
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple Polylines</title>
<style>
html,body,#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
</style>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
// This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing
// the path of William Kingsford Smith's first trans-Pacific flight between
// Oakland, CA, and Brisbane, Australia.

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng("<%=gps_y[0]%>","<%=gps_x[0]%>"),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var path_start = new Array();
  var path_end = new Array();

  <%for(int i = 0; i < gps_x.length;i++){%>
 <%if(i <= gps_x.length-2){%>
  path_start.push(new google.maps.LatLng("<%=gps_y[i]%>","<%=gps_x[i]%>"));
  path_end.push(new google.maps.LatLng("<%=gps_y[i+1]%>","<%=gps_x[i+1]%>"));
<%}else{
      break;
  }%>

<%}%>
    for ( var i = 0; i < path_start.length; i++) {
            var carpath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path : [ path_start[i], path_end[i] ],
                geodesic : true,
                strokeColor : '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity : 1.0,
                strokeWeight : 2,
            });
             setTimeout(function() { carpath.setMap(map); }, 100);

        }

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see at least one problem (I can't verify if that is the only problem without a link to your map).

You are adding all of the points on your path at the same time. Here's modified code for your loop:

```
var carPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    geodesic : true,
    strokeColor : '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity : 1.0,
    strokeWeight : 2
});
var carPath = new google.maps.MVCArray();
for ( var i = 0; i < path_start.length; i++) {
  if(i === 0) {
    carPath.push(path_start[i]);
    carPolyline.setPath(carPath);
  } else {
    setTimeout((function(latLng) {
      return function() {
        carPath.push(latLng);
      };
    })(path_start[i]), 100 * i);
  }
}
```

It didn't look to me like your path_end array was needed. I may have missed the point of it however.

Here is the edited (and working) jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jm3kL/4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the code, but the output is only the map without any polyline. Which link do you need? I needed the path_end array, because I thought that I have to give start and end point coordinates in each loop.

Comment: I need a link to your map website.

Comment: You got the point, but without being able to see the map I'm stuck with guessing. I can't tell if there are any script errors, whether lat,lng values are correct or a long laundry list of other possibilities.

Comment: I can add some coordinates, so you could just run the code with them. Would it be helpful?

Comment: What would be helpful is if you view source on your page and use it to create a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Could you have a look? I guess I am doing sth wrong. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/armminer/Jm3kL/) . Thanks!

Comment: Dear Chad, I just don't know how to thank you! :D I am stuck on this problem 4 days and couldn't find the solution, because I am not experienced in javascript. Thank you very much. 
Is it possible to change the color during this "animation"? I just have a parameter and wnat to change the color according to the value. Do you have any idea how can i do that?

Comment: Using something like `carPolyline.setOptions({strokeColor: '#00FF00'})`. But if you have further questions about this, you'll need to post a new question.

Comment: could you please have a look at this thread?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930530/update-the-google-maps-polyline-color-during-the-animation

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth,can i ask did you manually get the lat and lng coordinates?

Comment: @jemz I'm not sure what you are asking specifically. The JSFiddle is based on the output of the original question.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth,those coordinates that you push to the start and end

Comment: @jemz They were provided by the original poster. See http://jsfiddle.net/armminer/Jm3kL/

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth,your example is very helpful,just want to ask if we don't move the map the route will not be seen in the viewport,is it possible that the map will follow or adjust the viewport so that the route will be seen where it is heading?I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: @jemz You'll need to ask a separate question regarding this - it's beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth,Ok i will,can i ask permission to link my question to your jsfiddle?